# would this question be more appropriate in SF?

Tags: discussion, support

The following question was asked a few weeks ago.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554311/docker-on-windows-in-production

No one has been able to answer it on SO.

Would that question more fit in Server Fault as it is not a coding question, per se?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's OK on SO I think (as Docker/Win is just a dev tool...), and I just answered it there.